# cakephp need to place animated waiting icon

Tags: cakephp

I linked my page to paypal, I coded like this

```
<div class="paypal">
    <h1><?php __('Please wait while we transfering you to the payment gateway.');?></h1>
    <?php echo $paypal->submit(__('Click here if this page appears for more than 5 seconds', true), $paypalData); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('frmPaypal').submit();
    </script>
</div>
```

I need to place an animated gif waiting icon instead of button....

Comment: Why is this tagged cakephp? This is a html only issue IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to output the image using CakePHP:

```
echo $this->Html->image('loading.gif', array('alt' => 'Loading'));
```

Otherwise you can use HTML:

```
<img src="loading.gif">
```